# Having CP taken away after powering up a Pokemon.

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a Vaporeon that I powered up last week and after I powered it up, it says it received 39 CP. At first it gives the Vaporeon the 39 CP, then it immediately takes away 20. It doesn't show the CP being taken away, it just changes real fast after its powered and I'm out the CP, star dust and candies. It currently needs 4500 stardust, relative to the 6000 it would need if it was at the trainer cap, so I know it's not because I hit level 30 (this vape is lower than my 4 others which are at the level cap.)

This has happened to me 3 times and it has only happened to this one Vaporeon. I powered it up twice last week before I noticed this happening, so I didn't touch it until this morning when it happened again.

If it were at the level 30 trainer cap, it would only tell me its getting 20 and not 39, but this gives me 39 and then takes some away. it was around cp 2130 and now its 2191 after it's happened three times. :(

Any advice is appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have more than 1 Vaporeon?

Comment: I do, but im 100% sure its happening to this Vaporeon because it has a unique name and moveset.

Answer (score 5):

The CP of the Vaporeon you just powered up has increased correctly, the thing here is that you have more than 1 Vaporeon and there is a glitch that when you power up a pokemon and it's CP increases more than your next higher CP, it switches place, so it seems you lost some CP on that one.

Like this:

1. Dragonite CP 1020
2. Vaporeon CP 1010
3. Vaporeon CP 1000

If you power up the #3 CP 1000 to CP 1015, it will switch on the list to #2 but previously you were seeing the #3 on the list, so now it will display the CP 1010 and will seem to lose some CP, but you are looking at a different pokémon.

1. Dragonite CP 1020
2. Vaporeon CP 1015 ← powered up
3. Vaporeon CP 1010 ← seeing this

The same will happen after you power up the CP 1015 again:

1. Vaporeon CP 1030 ← powered up
2. Dragonite CP 1020 ← seeing this
3. Vaporeon CP 1010

You powered the Vaporeon CP 1015 to CP 1030 but that one was the #2 on this list and became #1, but now you see your Dragonite as it becomes the #2 on the list.

I hope Niantic fixes this soon.

Comment: I've noticed that and I have different names so I can keep track of them. This instances is a little different because I leveled up all the Vapes with Hydro Pump first, then I started using my extra star dust when available to level up the vapes with Aqua Tail. The one this happened to had a unique named compared to the others and was the only one with Aqua Tail that wasn't in a gym. So when I went to power it up, I was able to follow it. Unless the problem is a strange glitch where the names are stuck on the screen as the Pokemon shifts, but I know the CP lose happened to the vape in question

Comment: @Mike have you exited the Pokemon screen, come back and checked? While you're in there, there is in fact a glitch where you'd sometimes see all the wrong stuff about a Pokemon after they switched slots.

Comment: It's also dependant on your ordering. For example, I ordered my Pokemon by CP, and when levelling up my Pidgeot, it suddenly switched to my Poliwrath (because it surpassed it). Since this is one of the primary ways to order your Pokemon (i.e. if your group by name, or number, they will still be ordered by CP), you'll likely experience this a fair bit when levelling your Pokemon

Answer (score 0):

I am going to venture a guess that you have multiple Vaporeon around the same CP.

The last update to the game made it so that when you powered up a Pokemon, if it surpassed the CP of a Pokemon, the list would shift accordingly but whatever Pokemon was moved to the "place" the powered up Pokemon was in will be displayed. This is likely a bug and likely very confusing if you have multiple of the same Pokemon all in a row.

---

While this is much later than the original question here, many new answers have been popping up expressing that their own Pokemon's CP have been changing. This is the result of a server-side change by Niantic.

As of today (November 21, 2016), there has been a change to the way CP is calculated. This is now reflected in-game and the CP numbers of many Pokemon have been changed. See [this announcement by Niantic](http://pokemongolive.com/en/post/cp_update/):

> We have made adjustments to the CP (Combat Power) of various Pokémon. Some Pokémon, such as Alakazam, Rhydon, and Gengar will have their CP increased. Others will have their CP lowered. These changes will allow a more balanced and competitive battling and training experience in Gyms. We will continue to adjust the CP going forward to improve the game balance when necessary.

Comment: I do have a variety, 15 between 2k and 2.5k but they're each named after different Rick and Morty characters. The one in question (MrPoopyBHole) has shwifted in position, but the name stays the same so I could always track it on the menu. Though I have noticed how it switches to the Pokemon in that spot after you power one up and it moves on up in the list.

Comment: @MikeDeCook Oh, then that is odd. Did you confirm that they were actually the same, including moveset? Also when you go back to view the entire list, has it moved from its original place? It may be that the bug doesn't change the name, either. I haven't seen it happen between two Pokemon of the same species.

Comment: I did, this was the only Vaporeon with Aqua Tail that wasn't in a gym. I already capped all with Hydro Pump, so the rest of the Vapes that I could level up because they weren't in gyms had Water Pulse.